# Simple C/C++ library for network graph manipulation

Tags: library, c++, graphs, c

I'm currently working on a research project that makes use of proprietary software. I'm trying to replace the proprietary C libraries for graph representation. Doing this will make it easier to migrate our project to an open platform and make it available to everyone for free.

The project mixes C with C++, so if it's a C library we are going to adopt, it needs to play along nicely with C++.

The [current](https://support.riverbed.com/bin/support/static/html/lvkl1ogabskmj7vvkrjkbq92n8/modeler/Programmers%20Reference/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=dsa_19_graph.063.01.html) [libraries](https://support.riverbed.com/bin/support/static/html/lvkl1ogabskmj7vvkrjkbq92n8/modeler/Programmers%20Reference/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=dsa_13_djk.061.01.html) use pointers for everything and casts to and from `void*` in order to store and retrieve stuff.

It makes it fairly easy to:

- add and remove vertices
- add and remove edges
- get a list with the edges of a vertex
- get a list with the neighbors of a node
- calculate connected components
- calculate shortest paths (using [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm))

Vertices have type `PrgT_Graph_Vertex*` and can have an associated `void*` pointer to store related information. A similar logic is used with respect to edges. Here's a [concrete example](https://support.riverbed.com/bin/support/static/html/lvkl1ogabskmj7vvkrjkbq92n8/modeler/Programmers%20Reference/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=dsa_13_djk.061.16.html).

The replacement needs to have a license that does not enforce copyleft, so it can't be GPL. BSD-style licenses are fine.

[Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), BGL from now on, has an OK [license](http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt) and is part of a well-known suite. However, its documentation is fragmentary and looks like it was "patched up" together rather than thoughtfully "built". Removing vertices does not seem to be easy as it can mess with vertex indexes.

[Lemon Graph Library](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) has the same [license](https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/wiki/License) as the BGL, looks easier, but is not as actively maintained (see [roadmap](https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/roadmap)).

[Stanford SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/snap/index.html) has an OK [license](http://snap.stanford.edu/snap/license.html) is the one with the nicest website, but the documentation appears very lacking.

[iGraph](http://igraph.org/c/) is not an option because it's [GPL licensed](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Licenses.html). Also, from what I understand, it would require a wrapper to be used in C++.

[Network Graph Toolkit](http://math.nist.gov/~RPozo/ngraph/ngraph_toolkit_index.html), developed by the NIST, is released in the public domain but does not look like it's documented at all (aside from code comments).

BGL seems to be the one with the best guarantees it will remain actively developed. But it's also quite far from my current implementation logic and will take a lot of time just to get started with.

Any suggestion?

Comment: In BGL You can "remove" vertices more cheaply using this filtering adapter that they apparently have - vertices are just marked deleted (and occasionally you have to re-consolidate the graph).

Comment: If you know BGL and want some rep, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29109054/1600770) of mine on SO.

Comment: I actually don't know BGL well; I've worked in a group in which someone else was the graph representation guy and he used to complain about how BGL was this and BGL was that...

Comment: There is indeed much to complain about it. Has he found a more intuitive library?

Comment: We were already too committed to it and too busy with other things for him to really try to replace it. About the "much to complain" - do you have a link to someplace which does this complaining? That is, discusses shortcomings of the BGL?

Comment: You have been bumped to the main page. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Not really. I moved my project from a patchwork of C functions to Python + NetworkX. Nothing in this list even compares to it in terms of documentation. I learned Python using that library.

Comment: LEMON graph is maintained, even if it does not have a recent release. I find it to be a very nice and modern C++ library which is designed to be easy to use and understand (unlike the BGL which is a frustrating over-engineered mess that I always waste too much time on).

Comment: igraph is the easiest to use. It has a C interface, which means that *it does not need any sort of wrapper to use from C++*. But yes, it is GPL.

Answer (score 1):

I expect it is too late to help the original poster, but as this question came up in the 'Hot Network Questions' list, here is a recommendation.

The [STLPlus library](http://stlplus.sourceforge.net/) is actively maintained and has a nice [directed graph implementation](http://stlplus.sourceforge.net/stlplus3/docs/digraph.html). It is available under the BSD licence. There is a forum, the maintainer usually replies within a couple of days and is open to suggestions / improvements.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems so obvious that I am afraid that I have misunderstood the question.

Surely, nothing beats Graphviz? It's been around forever, is actively maintained and has great support.

I love it because it takes plain text input, which I can generate from my data of many diverse formats.

This

```
graph { 
    a -- b; 
    b -- c; 
    a -- c; 
    d -- c; 
    e -- c; 
    e -- a; 
}
```

produces this

[image]

No need to link it to your program, just run it as a shell command from within your app.

Is this what you mean by a network graph?

[image]

See many more [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=graphviz%20gallery&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyjZbWyNXSAhXELMAKHaj6DmEQ7AkIOQ&biw=1280&bih=640) and [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php).

Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I suspect GraphViz is about *drawing* network graphs, rather than building them and applying algorithms to analyze their properties, right?

Comment: Yes it is. Did I misundertsand? Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, by "graph representation" I meant "building the internal structure". I understand how that can be misleading. I need libraries for graph analysis and manipulation. Think about calculating centrality metrics and shortest paths. Still, your answer provides a great tool for graph visualization.

Comment: D'oh! Silly me. But, I am glad that you (and others) might have learned of a very useful tool. Take alook at [the gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) to see just how much it can do. Hope you get a real answer, though ;-)